# Rownumber to select non duplicate or distinct rows from a table. Invalid name ''

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select non-duplicate rows from emp_demo2 table:

**Table**:

```
CREATE TABLE Emp_demo3 (
                emp_ID INT,
                emp_Name NVARCHAR (50),
                emp_sal_K INT,
                emp_manager INT,
                joining_date date,
                last_time date) 
            GO

            INSERT INTO Emp_demo3 VALUES (1,'Ali', 200,2,'2010-01-28','2015-05-09')
            INSERT INTO Emp_demo3 VALUES (2,'Zaid', 770,4,'2008-01-28','2015-05-09')
            INSERT INTO Emp_demo3 VALUES (3,'Mohd', 1140,2,'2007-01-28','2015-05-09')
            INSERT INTO Emp_demo3 VALUES (4,'LILY', 770,Null,'2013-01-28','2015-05-09')
            INSERT INTO Emp_demo3 VALUES (5,'John', 1240,6,'2016-01-28','2015-05-09')
            INSERT INTO Emp_demo3 VALUES (6,'Mike', 1140,4,'2018-01-28','2015-05-09')
            INSERT INTO Emp_demo3 VALUES (5,'John', 1240,6,'2017-01-28','2015-05-09')
            INSERT INTO Emp_demo3 VALUES (3,'Mohd', 1140,2,'2010-01-28','2015-05-09')
```

**Code to add column date_difference**

```
alter table emp_demo3
add date_diff date
go
update emp_demo3 set date_diff = datediff(day,joining_date, last_time)
```

I am trying to calculate date difference in days between 2 dates. Please note that this is just a random table I created. I cannot change date formats in my original table. So please tell how to get date difference with existing date formats.

**Error**

```
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date
```

Comment: select distinct * from Emp_demo2

Comment: there is no column called `rowNum` in your table which you are using in `where` condition subquery. Also why you want to achieve this by using window function where it can be achieve with simple query?

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I wanted to know how to use row_number here since I am preparing for some interiew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_Number` to make partitions by columns which are the same. Then it is necessary just filter rows which have `rownum = 1`:

An example:

```
DECLARE  @Emp_demo2 TABLE (
            emp_ID INT,
            emp_Name NVARCHAR (50),
            emp_sal_K INT,
            emp_manager INT)         

INSERT INTO @Emp_demo2 VALUES (1,'Ali', 200,2)
INSERT INTO @Emp_demo2 VALUES (2,'Zaid', 770,4)
INSERT INTO @Emp_demo2 VALUES (3,'Mohd', 1140,2)
INSERT INTO @Emp_demo2 VALUES (4,'LILY', 770,Null)
INSERT INTO @Emp_demo2 VALUES (5,'John', 1240,6)
INSERT INTO @Emp_demo2 VALUES (6,'Mike', 1140,4)
INSERT INTO @Emp_demo2 VALUES (5,'John', 1240,6)
INSERT INTO @Emp_demo2 VALUES (3,'Mohd', 1140,2)


SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
     t.emp_ID
    , t.emp_Name
    , t.emp_sal_K
    , t.emp_manager
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.emp_Name, t.emp_sal_K, t.emp_manager
        ORDER BY t.emp_Name) AS RowNum
    FROM @Emp_demo2 AS t
)q
WHERE q.RowNum = 1
ORDER BY q.emp_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Following query is to find duplicates

```
select
    distinct emp_ID,
    emp_Name,
    emp_sal_K,
    emp_manager
from
(
  select *, 
    count(*) over (partition by emp_id) as total
    from Emp_demo2 e
) val
where total > 1
order by
    emp_ID
```

If you want only distinct values then you can use following

```
select
    distinct emp_ID,
    emp_Name,
    emp_sal_K,
    emp_manager
from Emp_demo2 e
order by
    emp_ID
```

Comment: PLs help with query using rownumber and self join..What is the problem with my approach

Answer (score 1):

METHOD 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * from @EmP_demo2
```

METHOD 2:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT *  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY EMP_ID) AS ROWNUM 
FROM @EMP_DEMO2 E
)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE ROWNUM=1
```

METHOD 3:
By using `Group by` also we ca avoid this duplicates.

Hope this works fine for your case

Answer (score 1):

you can use this query,

```
select * from (select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by emp_id order by emp_id) AS Rownum, *  from Emp_demo2 as e
)x
where x.Rownum = 1
```